Order vs. chaos: do they have “different kinds of information”?
There’s an idea in information theory that randomness/random data contains “more information”, for example because it takes more information to describe the data. A regular pattern such as 01010101… can be described with a function expressing an infinite alternating sequence; thus the description can be made much shorter than the original sequence.
One thought occurred to me: what if we just defined “randomness” as a primitive concept, where we do not have to spell out every single value for some random data, but view it on a general level as “amorphous information”, and then we can have a short description of it, like, “randomness level of 1”, where we consider different sets of random data to be isomorphic or more or less identical under that definition of randomness?
Then we would see a converse image of information: more order means more information, because it requires more “explicit intervention” to deviate from a ground state of “zero control or constraint over the primordial state of randomness”.
Have any mathematicians defined such a concept of “information” and shown how it compares to the Shannon-entropy idea?

The core of your post seems to me the second section with the terms “randomness” and “amorphous information”. You avoid to present a definition, but you prompt us to compare your intentionally undefined term with Shannon’s definition of information via entropy. How could this work?  - I think it’s not the intent of this site to take up your vague comments and arrange them in order.

While Wehler's criticism regarding the vagueness and ambiguity in the question is reasonable, we can resolve some basic issues.
Note that information, order, and chaos are three distinct concepts in philosophy that are controversial and interrelated, but somewhat distinct. Thus, we have to keep the basic definitions straight to understand their relationship. Order theory and chaos theory are two approaches to order and chaos that are fairly mathematical and canonical, but information itself is a little more conceptually contentious so it behooves us to start there.
Information in broad strokes is data that is meaningful. Note that necessarily invokes agency and computation. Beyond that characterization, there are all sorts of theories that surround the term. Here are some articles on it:

The philosophy of information is an attempt to reign in the various uses of the term with theories.
The Philosophy of Information (GB) by Luciano Floridi is one such attempt in the philosophy of information. Floridi is, as far as I can tell, the most famous and prolific of philosophers on the topic.
The Blackwell Guide to the Philosophy of Computing and Information (GB) is also edited by Floridi (and that exhausts my personal library on the topic though there are other authors; also, a GB search shows Floridi has a number of works in the academic presses on the topic).
Information theory is the classic theory that approaches information from a position of a bit-wise or character-wise syntactic analysis of language. Here the emphasis is on the very mathematical and technical interpretation of information as in the sense of information and communications technology.
Information (SEP) provides a general overview from the perspective of the philosophy of information.
Semantic Conceptions of Information (SEP) looks at some proffered differences by considering semantic rather syntactic units, though still mathematical in its approach.
Logic and Information (SEP) takes another approach by doing away with mathematical analysis and switching over to the formal semantics of logic instead.

Order is largely seen through the lens of the order relation which is a type of binary relation. Everyone is familiar with this arithmetically, but mathematicians do a great job abstracting this to various structures such as posets and lattices. Sequences, which map the naturals onto some domain, are our intuitive notion of order, and in set theory, can be understood in terms of the index set of another set. In a slightly broader notion, order is a form of hierarchy, which might be seen as a topological isomorphism for more arithmetic notions. In computer science, the use of the graphs and trees is pervasive and captures a notion of order too.
Chaos in chaos theory is seen as unpredictibility usually in a temporal sense. Predicting motion has always been a useful pursuit, and astronomers and physicists for instance have explored the three-body problem. Chaos, then, in a more technical sense might be understood as a notion in between ordered and unpredictable outcomes. Strange attractors demonstrate chaotic behavior.
Now, we are in a position to answer your questions.
You ask:

Have any mathematicians defined such a concept of “information” and shown how it compares to the Shannon-entropy idea?

Yes, there are syntactic and semantic analyses of information, some of them mathematical, and some of them linguistic.

where we consider different sets of random data to be isomorphic or more or less identical under that definition of randomness?

Now, you are introducing yet another term, randomness. I don't see a definition of randomness here in the SEP article Chance and Randomness that allows various classes, rather it is defined as a statistical property of a set. But not you're in algorithmic information theory and algorithmically random sequences. If one were to classify randomness, then it might be along the lines of different types of randomness not based on hierarchical, but classificatory considerations.

Order vs. chaos: do they have “different kinds of information”?

In common speech, order and chaos are antonyms, but it is possible to use more technical definitions which result in: yes, under order theory and chaos theory, the models which inform us are somewhat distinct. Descriptions of order are generally relational, sequential, and spatial in nature. The description of chaos is generally linked to the notion of randomness and temporality. But considering that temporality is a specific type of order, they are highly interrelated since sequences can be generated as a series of outputs over time. Of course, again, it all depends on the definition of information one begins with.
